# limit access to wordpress users to folders and php files

Tags: php, wordpress

First, sorry for my english.

I am developing a web application that works on wordpress. I have a folder called GSC, and inside it is my application.

The problem I have, is when I have to control access to users to that directory since all that part will be private, only for registered users.

I have tried with some plugin as wishlist member and only protects the main folder and has no control in subfolders so the application fails since it can not load all the necessary.

So I've searched everywhere and I can not find any more plugin, or I do not know if I should be by programming in each php file controlling if there is a user session, or if wordpress has something else to control access to folders, even look if it you can configure htaccess so that it depends on wordpress users but I do not know if you can.

If someone can give me some idea.

Thank you

Update:

My htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*gsc/formulario-clientes/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp-private.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Wp-private.php

```
<?php
/*
 * dl-file.php
 *
 * Protect uploaded files with login.
 * 
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37144/protect-wordpress-uploads-if-user-is-not-logged-in
 * 
 * @author hakre <http://hakre.wordpress.com/>
 * @license GPL-3.0+
 * @registry SPDX
 */



require_once('wp-load.php');
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/formatting.php';
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/capabilities.php';
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/user.php';
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/meta.php';
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/post.php';
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php';
require_once ABSPATH .  'wp-admin/includes/file.php';


 $path = get_home_path()."gsc" ;

is_user_logged_in() ||  auth_redirect();

//list($basedir) = array_values(array_intersect_key(wp_upload_dir(), array('basedir' => 1)))+array(NULL);
$basedir = $path;

$file =  rtrim($basedir,'/').'/'.str_replace('..', '', isset($_GET[ 'file' ])?'formulario-clientes/'.$_GET[ 'file' ]:'');


if (!$basedir || !is_file($file)) {
    status_header(404);
   // wp_redirect(home_url());
   die('404 &#8212; File not found.'.$file);
    exit();
}


$mime = wp_check_filetype($file);
if( false === $mime[ 'type' ] && function_exists( 'mime_content_type' ) )
    $mime[ 'type' ] = mime_content_type( $file );

if( $mime[ 'type' ] )
    $mimetype = $mime[ 'type' ];
else
    $mimetype = 'image/' . substr( $file, strrpos( $file, '.' ) + 1 );

header( 'Content-Type: ' . $mimetype ); // always send this
if ( false === strpos( $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'Microsoft-IIS' ) )
    header( 'Content-Length: ' . filesize( $file ) );

$last_modified = gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime( $file ) );
$etag = '"' . md5( $last_modified ) . '"';
header( "Last-Modified: $last_modified GMT" );
header( 'ETag: ' . $etag );
header( 'Expires: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + 100000000 ) . ' GMT' );

// Support for Conditional GET
$client_etag = isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] ) ? stripslashes( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] ) : false;

if( ! isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] ) )
    $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] = false;

$client_last_modified = trim( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] );
// If string is empty, return 0. If not, attempt to parse into a timestamp
$client_modified_timestamp = $client_last_modified ? strtotime( $client_last_modified ) : 0;

// Make a timestamp for our most recent modification...
$modified_timestamp = strtotime($last_modified);

if ( ( $client_last_modified && $client_etag )
    ? ( ( $client_modified_timestamp >= $modified_timestamp) && ( $client_etag == $etag ) )
    : ( ( $client_modified_timestamp >= $modified_timestamp) || ( $client_etag == $etag ) )
    ) {
    status_header( 304 );
    exit;
}

// If we made it this far, just serve the file
readfile( $file );
```

It works and it allows me to access by wordpress user, except that a  that I have in the code appears as  and I do not know why.

any idea?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverFlow. In order to get quality answers, please provide pertinent code blocks that you have. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I think that the question better be in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Possible dublicate of [How to Protect Uploads, if User is not Logged In?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37144/how-to-protect-uploads-if-user-is-not-logged-in)

TL;DR:
So what you can do is make a redirect to a php file, and check if a user is logged in or not.

So if you want to protect the `upload` folder, put this in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ check-auth.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Example of file to use, to check for auth [is found here](https://gist.github.com/hakre/1552239).

Comment: Yes Its similar but I want to protect all files in GSC folder and subfolder. I'm going to try, to see if it works

Comment: I have tried it and it allows me to access by wordpress user, except that a <require_once> that I have in the code appears as <! - require_once -> and I do not know why.

any ideas? Up I have put my htaccess